# docker-compose with Django and Postgresql: Password does not match for user "postgres"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am following exactly the django, psql, docker tutorial https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/

and I keep getting the error:

```
Password does not match for user "postgres"
```

and from django I am getting:

```
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
web_1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

from Postgresql I am getting

```
2021-08-16 06:44:09.563 UTC [1] LOG: starting PostgreSQL 13.4 (Debian 13.4-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit

2021-08-16 06:44:09.572 UTC [1] LOG: listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432

2021-08-16 06:44:09.581 UTC [1] LOG: listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432

2021-08-16 06:44:09.668 UTC [1] LOG: listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"

2021-08-16 06:44:09.885 UTC [26] LOG: database system was shut down at 2021-08-16 06:37:34 UTC

2021-08-16 06:44:09.960 UTC [1] LOG: database system is ready to accept connections

2021-08-16 06:44:10.942 UTC [33] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

2021-08-16 06:44:10.942 UTC [33] DETAIL: Password does not match for user "postgres".

Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host all all all md5"



PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
```

docker-compose.yml

```
        version: "3.9"
        
        services:
          db:
            image: postgres
            volumes:
              - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            environment:
              - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
              - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
              - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
          web:
            build: .
            command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
            volumes:
              - .:/code
            ports:
              - "8000:8000"
            depends_on:
              - db
```

Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

Django database settings

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

I think the only thing that is stopping it from working is the psql password not working from django side

Comment: clear the docker volume by running `docker-compose down` (from the project directory) and then run the `docker-compose up`

Comment: Can you show us actual error?

Comment: I added the postgresql errors as well. I just checked it by removing the volume part of docker-compose and running that, and it worked! I changed the volume to different directories such as

            volumes:
              - ./data/db:/var/lib/psql2/data2

and that worked too!

so we nailed it down to the volume part, but I am unsure of how I can fully remove the persistent data in the volume that I have pruned, and force removed the image, container, and volume.